# extra space between A and IMG elements

Tags: css

i have this code (https://jsfiddle.net/26gvaekf/1/) and want that `A` height was exactly at `IMG` boundaries. However, there is small space after `IMG`

[image]

can anybody explain, why this happens? and  which css property i should use (only not `float` one).

Comment: Thanks, I havent seen that topic.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/26gvaekf/2/)

css

```
img {
  vertical-align:top /* img are default bottom aligned make it to top */
}

/* for demonstration purpose */
a {
  display: inline-block /* to cover your img completely */
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` doesnt help. only `block` helps in my case.

Comment: yeah you can use bloack on anchor its just for representation so you see it in fiddle